# URLs for images in .xcassets

Tags: swift, initialization, xcasset, imessage-extension, mssticker

I’m working on a sticker pack app. It’s technically an iMessage extension because I’d like to use advanced features like in-app purchases.

I’ve put all the stickers into the `Stickers.xcassets` file, but I can’t figure out how to get URLs for those stickers.

I know I can get images from `.xcassets` by typing `UIImage(named: "sticker.png")`, but the `MSSticker` [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/mssticker/1829445-init) only accepts the URL: `init(contentsOfFileURL:localizedDescription:)`.

How do I get URLs for files in `.xcassets`?

P.S. I am also aware I can put the stickers into a regular folder in project navigator, and it’s a temporary solution that’s in use now. But the goal is to use `.xcassets` because it supports certain features, such as App Thinning.

Comment: well just type in the name of the image, the code completion will complete the name and that's your UIImage you can use...?

Comment: No, it doesn’t work like this. You can’t initialize an instance of `MSSticker` with `UIImage`—you’re required to provide a URL.